# vb.net can't use button.PerformClick after control Validated

Tags: vb.net, forms

in the form, i need check the textbox detail,so i use the Validated method.i also have a button to save form detail.and the button bind F10.
the text box Validated method

```
Private Sub txtReportCD_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtReportCD.Validated

    If txtReportCD.Text <> String.Empty Then
        cboReportName.Value = txtReportCD.Text.Trim
    Else
        CommonMsg.showMsg("the CD not be empty")
    End If

End Sub
```

the form keydown

```
Private Sub form_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Alt AndAlso e.Control AndAlso e.Shift Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case e.KeyCode

        'save data
        Case Keys.F10
            ClickButton(Me.btnSaveData, e)

            e.Handled = True

    End Select
End Sub
```

the ClickButton method

```
Private Sub ClickButton(ByVal btn As ButtonKdcCtrl, e As KeyEventArgs)
    e.Handled = True

    If e.Alt OrElse e.Control OrElse e.Shift Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If btn.Enabled Then
        btn.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

the btnSaveData method

```
Private Sub btnSaveData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveData.Click
    CommonMsg.showMsg("begin save data")
    'do save form data
End Sub
```

when focus in txtReportCD,and i press F10 key. the form first do [btn.PerformClick], then do [txtReportCD_Validated] **twice**,last do [btnSaveData_Click].

but when focus in txtReportCD,and i click btnSavaData button.
the form first do [txtReportCD_Validated] **once** and not do [btnSaveData_Click].

how can i do,make when i press F10,the form do [txtReportCD_Validated] **once**
and the [btnSaveData_Click] not be call

PS: the txtReportCD text always empty.

Comment: Firstly, you don't do validation in the `Validated` event handler. Validation occurs in the `Validating` event handler. `Validated` is for performing an action after the control has passed validation.

Comment: We can't see what CommonMsg.showMsg() does, but it is guessable.  MessageBox.Show() is pretty troublesome in any event handler that runs due to a focus change, like Validated, since it jerks the focus away.  Stops a button click from working, for one.  Realistically you can only use a message box in the Validating event and when you set e.Cancel = True.  Instead of slapping the user with message boxes, consider a milder form of feedback with StatusStrip or Label or ErrorProvider.

Comment: for some reason i must use Validated,and it can not use e.Cancel = ture